# ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers' : but innate

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with Django version conflicting.

when I run my Django project, I got message.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py in <module>()
     21 try:
---> 22     from django.urls import (
     23         NoReverseMatch, RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver, ResolverMatch, Resolver404, get_script_prefix, reverse, reverse_lazy, resolve

ImportError: cannot import name 'RegexURLPattern'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0639a9fdda0c> in <module>()
      1 from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus
      2 from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
----> 3 from hospital.serializers import HospitalSerializer

~/earlierdoctorserver/hospital/serializers.py in <module>()
----> 1 from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
      2 from .models import Hospital
      3
      4 class HospitalSerializer(ModelSerializer):
      5         class Meta:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in <module>()
     28 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
     29
---> 30 from rest_framework.compat import JSONField as ModelJSONField
     31 from rest_framework.compat import postgres_fields, set_many, unicode_to_repr
     32 from rest_framework.exceptions import ErrorDetail, ValidationError

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py in <module>()
     24     )
     25 except ImportError:
---> 26     from django.core.urlresolvers import (  # Will be removed in Django 2.0
     27         NoReverseMatch, RegexURLPattern, RegexURLResolver, ResolverMatch, Resolver404, get_script_prefix, reverse, reverse_lazy, resolve
     28     )

ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

Looking straight at the lines of code, my project does not have that statement, and there seems to be a problem with the package in the local repository. pip upgrades, etc. are all up to date, how do I fix them?

thanks.

Comment: Which Django version?

Comment: @KlausD. using version of Django 2.0.1

Comment: What version of django-rest-framework are you using? Looks like this is related to this bug: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5456

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar message trying to run `python manage.py show_urls` after upgrading to Django 2.

Upgrading `django-extensions` solved the issue for me, but in your case it looks like you need to upgrade your Compat and Rest Framework libraries.